# Mockito ArgumentMatcher saying Arguments are Different

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am using Mockito for Unit testing and I am using ArgumentMatcher to check if a particular field of an argument has a particular value.

I have a StatusMatcher class that extends ArgumentMatcher and checks whether an object of class MyClass has a particular value in status field. The way I am invoking this in the tests is:

```
verify(myDAO, times(1)).update(argThat(new StatusMatcher("SomeStatus")));
```

Here `update` is the method of the DAO that is getting called with some MyClass object. I want to see if it has the correct status or not. This is what I get:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
myDAO.update(
    <Status matcher>
);
-> at com.foo.bar.MyTest.test1 
Actual invocation has different arguments:
myDAO.update(
    com.foo.bar.MyClass
);
```

Note that this is working perfectly for all the test cases except one test case. So I know the StatusMatcher etc. have been coded correctly. I am not sure what is different about the method where its getting this exception.

What I want to know is: under what conditions will the ArgumentMatcher throw such exception so I can find out what I am missing (It is not for me to paste the actual method codes)
Please tell me if the explanation is not clear enough, and I will try to improve it. Thanks for reading this far :)

EDIT: Here is the code for my StatusMatcher class

```
    private class StatusMatcher extends ArgumentMatcher<MyClass> {

    private String status;
    public StatusMatcher(String hs) { 
        status = hs;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object argument) {

        return status.equals(((MyClass)argument).getStatus());
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code of `StatusMatcher` and `MyClass`?

Comment: The problem seems to be in `StatusMatcher`.  Please show it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Like you said, it fails because the arguments are different. Take a look at the test below and you'll see that the second test method will fail because the status in your `MyClass` instance is different from `SomeStatus` that you passed in the matcher.

```
public class MatcherTest {

    class MyClass{
        private String status;

        MyClass(String status) {
            this.status = status;
        }

        public String getStatus(){
            return status;
        }
    }

    class MyDao {
        public void update(MyClass myClass){}
    }

    class StatusMatcher extends ArgumentMatcher<MyClass> {
        private String status;
        public StatusMatcher(String hs) {
            status = hs;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matches(Object argument) {
            return status.equals(((MyClass)argument).getStatus());
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldMatchStatus(){
        MyDao mock = mock(MyDao.class);
        mock.update(new MyClass("expectedStatus"));
        verify(mock, times(1)).update(argThat(new StatusMatcher("expectedStatus")));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldNotMatchStatus(){
        MyDao mock = mock(MyDao.class);
        mock.update(new MyClass("unexpectedStatus"));
        /* THE BELLOW WILL FAIL BECAUSE ARGUMENTS ARE DIFFERENT */
        verify(mock, times(1)).update(argThat(new StatusMatcher("expectedStatus")));
    }
}
```

I could take a wild guess that you could be reusing variables, or have a static field, etc. But without seeing your test code, no one can tell.

Comment: Ah! I see it now. This IS the reason why it is failing. I got mislead because of the wording of the error. It sounds as if there is a type mismatch. Actually it is just a different value. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, the message is not self explanatory and may cause confusion. Glad I could help, cheers

Comment: I don't know if this is going to be helpful to anybody, but I sometimes use something like verify(mock).method(any(MyClass.class)). It's useful when it doesn't really matter what you pass in it's nice to avoid this kind of error.

Comment: This comment above should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

- Try to simplify the test / code under test.  Do you really need to
  mutate arguments and also verify stubbing?  Both of those actions
- might indicate a code smell. Relax the argument verification and
- use some kind of any() matcher Perform validation of arguments in the

Comment: this answers seems to be incomplete

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue. Below is the error and its solution:

```
error: Argument(s) are different! Wanted:

    tradeMaintenanceDao.updateTradesMaintData(.....
```

I used the following statement to resolve it:

```
verify(tradeMaintenanceDao, times(1))
    .updateTradesMaintData(anyString(), anyList(), anyList(), anyString(), anyString());
```

The original cause was:

```
verify(tradeMaintenanceDao, times(1)).updateTradesMaintData(userName, tradeStatusList, tradeReasonList, notes, pendStatus);
```

Comment: This is not really a solution since you are weakening your test here, saying that it'd pass even with different string content. You might want to consider using Mockito.eq(myString).

Answer (score 0):

For others that are facing a similar issue here is how I fixed it.

The code below will throw the following error if you pass in a new instance of an object. All you have to do in this case is create a variable since it will not create a new reference in memory.

```
@Test
void shouldLogExceptionWithType() {
    mongoDao = mock(MongoDao.class);
    StepDetail stepDetail = StepDetail.builder()
            .table("some table")
            .batchType("Some batch type")
            .build();
    doCallRealMethod().when(mongoDao).logException(new Exception(), stepDetail.getBatchType().getName());
    mongoDao.logException(new Exception(), stepDetail.getBatchType().getName());
    verify(mongoDao, times(1)).logException(new Exception(), stepDetail.getBatchType().getName());
}
```

Code Fixed:

```
@Test
void shouldLogExceptionWithType() {
    mongoDao = mock(MongoDao.class);
    StepDetail stepDetail = StepDetail.builder()
            .table("some table")
            .batchType("Some batch type")
            .build();
    Exception exception = new Exception();
    doCallRealMethod().when(mongoDao).logException(exception, stepDetail.getBatchType().getName());
    mongoDao.logException(exception, stepDetail.getBatchType().getName());
    verify(mongoDao, times(1)).logException(exception, stepDetail.getBatchType().getName());
}
```